# Why is this not correct for computing $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{4}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^1 x^{n}-4x^{2n}+x^{n-1} {\rm d}x\\
&=\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  x^{n}-4x^{2n}+x^{n-1} {\rm d}x\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x}{1-x}+\frac{4x^2}{x^2-1}+\frac{1}{1-x} \right) {\rm d}x\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{3x+1}{x+1} {\rm d}x\\
&=3x-2\ln(x+1)\bigg|_0^1\\
&=3-2\ln 2
\end{align*}

Comment: Did you verify the conditions for which there is uniform convergence?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}$ is not convergent.

Comment: On the other hand, note that $$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^N\,\frac{1}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}&=\sum_{n=1}^N\,\Biggl(4\left(-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\Biggr)\\
&=4-4\,\sum_{n=1}^{2N+1}\,\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}-\left(1-\frac{1}{N+1}\right)
\\
&=3-4\,\sum_{n=1}^{2N+1}\,\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}+\frac{1}{N+1}
\end{align}$$
for every positive integer $N$.  Therefore,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\frac{1}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\,\sum_{n=1}^N\,\frac{1}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}=3-4\,\ln(2)\,,$$ since $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\ln(2)\,.$$

Answer (score 5):

Because you have no reason to assume that$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1x^n-4x^{2n}+x^{n-1}\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n-4x^{2n}+x^{n-1}\,\mathrm dx.$$